# Azure SQL Hyperscale Tier

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am not sure if this is a simple question. I have looked online, tried to be logical, but could not find a clear answer - Does the hyperscale tier of Azure SQL database support schema-based separation of database objects?

The reason why I am confused- The hyperscale documentation states it is a single database - [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/service-tier-hyperscale-frequently-asked-questions-faq#how-does-the-hyperscale-service-tier-differ-from-the-general-purpose-and-business-critical-service-tiers:~:text=Single%20database,-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/service-tier-hyperscale-frequently-asked-questions-faq#how-does-the-hyperscale-service-tier-differ-from-the-general-purpose-and-business-critical-service-tiers:%7E:text=Single%20database,-SQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Features for hyperscale is similar with what we already have with other tiers. Hyperscale does support schema-based separation of database objects. Once you provisioned a new database you can set up new login and users, and based on their permission of different schema only those will be accessible.

***Below screenshot shows login1 has select permission on dbo schema and does not have it on SalesLT, only dbo objects are visible.***(Used SSMS, we can check same through Query editor in Azure portal)

[image]
***Below screenshot shows login2 has select permission on SalesLT schema and does not have it on dbo, only SalesLT objects are visible***
[image]